# Intermittent "File in Use" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, exception

I have some code that I wrote to basically clear out the directory every time the program runs through this point.  I didn't want to bother enumerating files.  If this is a bad way to do this, please tell me.

My main question, however, is about how to deal with the following: one of the files in the folder appears to be in use when it is most certainly not.  The program runs on a ButtonClick event, and it exploded the first four or five times, but it worked after I confirmed that nobody was using the file on the server.  There is only one person besides myself that would have been using it, and he confirmed that there was nothing running on his side that would be touching the file.  Any ideas for what would cause this error/how to avoid it/how to handle it?

I am also having trouble reproducing the error...

```
string directory = @"\\server\directory\folder\";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

    if (di.Exists)
        di.Delete(true);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
```

Comment: I think you have to delete underlying files

Comment: Possibly somebody was using the file and didn't dispose the FileStream. Then the file becomes available once the GC collects the FileStream.

Comment: Antivirus can be a pain here, although hard to say since the sample above doesn't touch any files...

Comment: @Marc Gravell The sample touches any and all files within the directory. `Delete(true)` will delete subdirectories and files within the directory referred by the `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: It's unrelated to the question, but beware of race conditions. The thread or application can be preempted pretty much anywhere within that snippet, and if the preempting thread also deals with the directory in question, you run the risk of getting an exception thrown. There is also the issue of concurrency between multiple instances of code like the above running simultaneously, possibly on different hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows XP, this may help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx#remove_open_handles

Just an extract from the top of this page :
"If you are running Windows XP or earlier, a delete operation on a file or directory that follows an enumeration could fail if there is an open handle that remains on one of the enumerated directories or files."

You may also use a software like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to identify the process locking your file.

Comment: I know it took some time to get to this, but this ended up being the source of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in use, then someone is most certainly using it. :)

If you can access the server the files reside on, you can use a tool such as [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find out which process has opened the file.

Comment: Except that nobody was.  The process that might've been using it wasn't started because this part was failing, and there is only one person beside myself that would have been.  I checked with him, and he confirmed that he had neither started the next process nor touched the files yet.  That also doesn't explain why this would be intermittent.

Comment: @SeanVDH Again, if Windows reports that the file is in use, then it is in use. Check who is using it with Process Explorer and deal with the issue from there.

Comment: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) would be better in this case -- allows logging of all accesses. Maybe hard to see transient accesses in Process Explorer.